# Use a Crypto algorithm to store and retrieve User name and User Password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using devise gem to the user registration and session handling module of my application.
I want to encrypt usernames and passwords so that i can store that in db and in order to use that both in my app I can retrieve that from db and use them. Any Help?

Comment: you should save them in MF5 hashes or SHA-1 hashes in the db and then can retrieve it

Comment: Check out [attr_encrypted](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/attr_encrypted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devise already does this. So, you don't have to care about encryption of password.

Comment: I know Devise already takes care about encryption of password But I have to do encryption and decryption by myself